# Ajax.BeginForm not working in chrome MVC 5

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-chrome, asp.net-mvc-5, ajax.beginform

I am currently trying to implement an Ajax form in MVC 5.

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Requirement", "Purchase", null, new AjaxOptions { OnSuccess = "redirectionClick", OnFailure = "Retry", HttpMethod = "POST" }, new { id = "RequirementForm", autocomplete = "off" }))
{
   //Various input fields
   @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
   <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary EqualSized" id="SubmitBtn" style="width:30%">
   <input type="button" value="Reset" id="Reset" class="btn btn-primary EqualSized" style="width:30%">
}
```

The functions under script tag:

```
function CloseModals() {
    $('.modal').modal('hide');
    $('body').removeClass('modal-open');
    $('div.modal-backdrop').remove();
}

function redirectionClick() {
    CloseModals();
    bootbox.alert("Saved Successfully!");
    $.ajax({
        url: "@Url.Action("Requirement", "Purchase")",
        async: false,
        success: function (result) {
            $('#PageData').html(result);
        }
    })
}

function Retry() {
    alert('Unknown Error, Please try submitting the form again!');
    $('#SubmitBtn').attr('disabled', false);
}

$('#SubmitBtn').click(function () {
    if ($('#RequirementForm').valid())
        $(this).attr('disabled', true);
});
```

And my controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public void Requirement(Requirement Details)
{
  //Logic
}
```

The above code works in FireFox and IE, but not in Chrome. Is there something I am missing in this?

Comment: Why do you have `OnSuccess = "redirectionClick"` which means that after submitting to the `Requirement()` method, you then do another ajax call to the same method?

Comment: The `redirectionClick` is a call to the HttpGet action in the controller. To view the refreshed data

Comment: So why not just use the `UpdateTargetId` option and return the partial in the post method? (seems a strange way of doing this - making 2 calls instead of 1)

Comment: It was done this way because the form will be in a modal. And updating directly caused issues main window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a submit button is disabled, i don't think it can submit a form, your click handler is firing before your submit handler.

try changing your click handler to this

```
$('#SubmitBtn').click(function () {
    if ($('#RequirementForm').valid())
         $(this).prop('disabled', true).closest('form').submit();
});
```

The other way is to handler the submit on the form instead, and disable the button in there if the form is valid.  you can use the onbegin or submit event for that

Comment: Welcome to the world of web dev, it's not uncommon to find differences in how browsers behave

Comment: It works :-) had to specify `return false;` as the form was getting submitted twice in IE